# What is the generalization of polynomial functors to symmetric monoidal categories called?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Let $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ be a functor, where $\mathcal{C}$ is a category with finite products and coproducts. we say it is polynomial if it is of the form:

$F(X) = A_n \times X^n + \dots + A_1 \times X + A_0$

Where $+$ denotes a coproduct in $\mathcal{C}$, $\times$ a product, and $X^n = X \times X \times X \times \dots \times X$, the n-fold product of $X$ with itself.

Now, what if, instead of having products, we only have a symmetric monoidal category. Then is there a term for a functor of the form

$$F(X) = A_n \otimes X^{\otimes n} + \dots + A_1 \otimes X + A_0$$

where $X^{\otimes n}$ now denotes the n-fold tensor product with respect to the symmetric monoidal operation in question. Does this type of functor have a name in the literature?

Comment: I would still call it a polynomial functor. Note that you probably want the symmetric monoidal structure to distribute over coproducts.

Comment: Typo (I think): the last equation should be $F(X) = A_n\otimes X^{\otimes n} + \dots + A_1\otimes X +A_0$ (I won't edit because I'm not sure that is what you intend to mean).

Comment: @Pece That's correct, I'll edit the question accordingly.